# Punctuation of a list within a list

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

I'm trying to form a list like the following:

> I'm interested in new technologies such as web development using various javascript packages including: node.js;meteor.js;backbone.js, contributing to open source projects on github, and getting my hands deep into code.

Is the way I list the three javascript packages correct? Or would you suggest something different?

Comment: Where is the "list within a list"?

Comment: Does that make it more concise ?

Comment: I would suggest putting the sublist in parenthesis, like so - , javascript packages (including node.js, meteor.js, backbone.js and more),

Comment: You may find [ell.se] useful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suitable for [ell.se] (and is also most likely a duplicate!)

Answer (score 4):

Because of your use of commas and semi-colons, it's not exactly clear how the lists are organised, but assuming this:

- new technologies
- web development using varying javascript packages including:

  - node.js;
  - meteor.js;
  - backbone.js,
- contributing to open source projects on github,
- and getting my hands deep into code.

...then — if you can't actually use bullet points like that — I would use the commas and semi-colons exactly the other way round. A semi-colon is a bigger break/divider than a comma.

> I'm interested in: new technologies; web development using varying javascript packages including node.js, meteor.js and backbone.js; contributing to open source projects on github; and getting my hands deep into code.

Note that as well as using semi-colons, the colon introduces the **whole** list rather than the sub-list. And the sub-list includes an *and* and is entirely self-contained.

Comment: Thank you for untangling the lists in the original question! I had a hard time understanding it. I agree that colon, semicolon, comma is the right hierarchy here, from broadest to most specific.

Comment: It should be stressed that semicolons, just like commas and colons, are always followed by a whitespace. OP's original question did get this right, actually. But his edit did not.

Answer (score 0):

I normally like to do this for a list within a list.

I have the following computer parts: monitor, hdds (SDD/Flash Drive/ USB), keyboards (US/UK/JP/IND/ES). If you are interested please contact me on 555-555-555.

As you can see `keyboards` and `hdds` are plural, thus your list within a list would start after these words.

This for me works very well if you are trying to put everything in a few lines. However the best by far is to use a `list function (bullet points)` within [MS Word](http://www.ssa.gov/accessibility/checklists/img/ListFormatting_IncreaseIndent.png).